# Django Rest: ImportError: cannot import name "model name"

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

In Django Rest, am getting the following error. Could any one trace whats the mistake I was done

My APP structure

```
  test_APP

  abc_APP
```

In abc_APP models.py I am trying to access **Test** model, but I am getting the following error. may be due to reverse loop ? if yes, how to fix ?

```
abc_APP # models.py

from test_APP.models import Test


ImportError: cannot import name Test
```

Comment: post your settings.py file

Comment: As you rightly guessed it's very likely to be due to a cyclic include. You are probably including the model in your test but you are trying to import the test into the model. It's most unusual to import a test into a model why do you want to do that?